# probability question negative in a venn diagram

Tags: probability

If P(A')=.2 and P(B)=.2 and P(A∩B)=.6 Find P(AUB)

I made a venn diagram put .6 in the middle. Calculated if B = .2 then the other portion of b has to be -.4 ?? I have never seen a negative in the Venn before? Lost!!

Then if A' =.2, then A must be everything else in B or .8 so how is B = .8 and .2
I am lost please help me.
thank you.

Comment: Define $A'$ please

Also, $P(A\cap B)>P(B)$ is not possible

Answer (score 0):

It is impossible that the probability of the intersection exceeds the probability of either outcome treated independently.  (I have seen this question published elsewhere.  It is malformed.)